# How to use JS to retreive API data

Tags: javascript, api

I have written a basic API in PHP on my site (domain1.com). I need to load a simple form on another site (domain2.com) by placing a simple JS file on the other site. JS needs to access my API and format the form based on returned data.

**Question:** should I keep my JS file on initial site, with all the JS code in it and just let the other site include it like this

```
<script src="https://domain1.com/api.js?form=domain2"></script>
```

or shall I let the other site place a JS code, something like this:

```
<script>
    var form = ... // send request to https://domain1.com/api/form
</script>
```

I'm sure it's a common knowledge, but I really never had to deal with this sort of issues, so, if you don't wish to answer, please don't mark for "close".

Comment: Have you tried Fetch yet ? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch

fetch('http://example.com/movies.json')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => console.log(data));

Comment: I have not, but I am definitely going to try this now.

Comment: Generally, I would prefer the second one; because until and unless we are not talking about Node; js is client side scripting language and since second site shows the form it has to be kept there

Comment: @Mandy8055 No, we're not talking about Node.js/ I personally prefer jQuery but I want to make it as simple as possible for others implement my code on their side. I was under the impression that I could format my output and return it as json to output on the external site, where they place my JS link. In fact the idea I had for to compile my HTML on my server based on domain2-specific ID and then return it for output. The trick is to send user selections from that form back to my db on domain1.com

Comment: I understood. Given that it's a new area for me, any tutorial/example suggestions?

Comment: Okay; so you want how can you do it in javascript?Best thing to use is [**fetch**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) along with  [**async-await**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function). [**This**](https://dev.to/shoupn/javascript-fetch-api-and-using-asyncawait-47mp) might help as starting point.

Comment: OK, the stars are aligning -  two recommendations for fetch() and from very little that I've read about it it does not need another framework. Thanks a bunch for the tip.